# Chapter labeling issue on Lyx

Tags: lyx, languages

I am creating a book document in Lyx in Italian using the standard book class.

On the display I am shown chapter labels in Italian (correctly), but when I preview the document as PDF the label changes to English and I cannot take it out.

Can anyone help please?

[image]

PREAMBLE:

```
    %% LyX 2.3.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
    %% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,italian]{book}
    \usepackage{bookman}
    \usepackage{avant}
    \usepackage{courier}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
    \usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \synctex=-1
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pdfcolmk}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
    \usepackage{ulem}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    
    \makeatletter
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
    \pdfpageheight\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
    
    \providecolor{lyxadded}{rgb}{0,0,1}
    \providecolor{lyxdeleted}{rgb}{1,0,0}
    %% Change tracking with ulem
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\color{lyxadded}{}#3}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxdeleted}[3]{{\color{lyxdeleted}\lyxsout{#3}}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxsout}[1]{\ifx\\#1\else\sout{#1}\fi}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \numberwithin{figure}{section}
    
    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
    \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{babel}
    \begin{document}
    \pagebreak{}
    \title{\textbf{All'inizio la democrazia era diretta}\\
    \textbf{Moritz Rittinghausen}\\
    \textbf{\Large{}e la democrazia diretta nel mondo moderno}}
    \author{\pagebreak}
    
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents{}
    
    \pagebreak{}
    
    \part*{PARTE PRIMA}
    
    \chapter{Introduzione}
    
    \section{La Germania e la democrazia: Il Vormärz più lungo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please copy your preamble as code, not as screenshot? I'd like to see, which language specific setting you use. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for looking. I stumbled over another issue, that of installing the svmono in italian in Lyx. I have texlive and Debian 10.4. I copied the directory with the Springer svmono italian format all over the place, from texlive directories to .lyx to others, but all I get is "cannot find svmono.cls". By the  way, I did not dare to "manipulate" the code directly, it is how it was created by using the Lyx settings and preferences, nothing else added.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know if this will solve it, but you should specify the language with babel, like this: \usepackage [italian]{babel}. And hopefully your system has this one installed: https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-italian?lang=en ;-) // If Lyx works like MiKTeX I'm using, it can ask for downloading missing packages, styles or fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Not a sloution, but result of a quick test.

May be, using Lyx is the main problem?

I tried compiling your MWE, but it failed with errors on MiKTeX. So to localize the problem I commented out almost everything from the preamble, like this:

```
%% LyX 2.3.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
    %% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,italian]{book}
%    \usepackage{bookman}
 %   \usepackage{avant}
%    \usepackage{courier}
%    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
%    \usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
%    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%    \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
%    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%    \synctex=-1
%    \usepackage{xcolor}
%    \usepackage{pdfcolmk}
%    \usepackage{amsmath}
 %   \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%    \PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
 %   \usepackage{ulem}
 %   \usepackage{microtype}
    
%    \makeatletter
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%    \pdfpageheight\paperheight
%    \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
    
%    \providecolor{lyxadded}{rgb}{0,0,1}
%    \providecolor{lyxdeleted}{rgb}{1,0,0}
    %% Change tracking with ulem
%    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\color{lyxadded}{}#3}}
%    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxdeleted}[3]{{\color{lyxdeleted}\lyxsout{#3}}}
%    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxsout}[1]{\ifx\\#1\else\sout{#1}\fi}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
%    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
%    \numberwithin{figure}{section}
    
%    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
 %   \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
    \pagebreak{}
    \title{\textbf{All'inizio la democrazia era diretta}\\
    \textbf{Moritz Rittinghausen}\\
    \textbf{\Large{}e la democrazia diretta nel mondo moderno}}
    \author{\pagebreak}
    
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents{}
    
    \pagebreak{}
    
    \part*{PARTE PRIMA}
    
    \chapter{Introduzione}
    
    \section{La Germania e la democrazia: Il Vormärz più lungo}
\end{document}
```

And it compiled. Here are some screenshots from the various parts:

[image: Compile on MiKTeX]

So, perhaps replacing Lyx is part of the solution? Preambles can grow considerably, ONCE content grows. As a reference, in such an early stage I probably wouldn't have entered so many code lines there manually. But that's just my way of working ... Lyx seems to follow a different route.

So for the moment I cancel my next steps to further zoom-in on the trouble-makers, which would have been to activate the preamble (i.e. remove the `%'s` ) step by step, until errors are reported again.

**P.S.**: For your reference I activated the various preamble lines by removing the `%'s`, starting from top. So basically your code is fine and it produces the screenshot as I posted earlier.

Remarks #1-#4 may be specific to my installation and options chosen.
#5 however **does not** print the date on the title-page.

This version compiles on my system, as indicated.

```
%% LyX 2.3.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
    %% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,italian]{book}
    \usepackage{bookman}    % #1 LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pbk/m/n' undefined
    \usepackage{avant}
    \usepackage{courier}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
%    \usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc} % #2 ! Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \synctex=-1
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pdfcolmk}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
    \usepackage{ulem}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    
    \makeatletter
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%    \pdfpageheight\paperheight % #3 ! Undefined control sequence. \pdfpageheight
%    \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth % #4 ! Undefined control sequence. \pdfpawidth
    
    \providecolor{lyxadded}{rgb}{0,0,1}
    \providecolor{lyxdeleted}{rgb}{1,0,0}
    %% Change tracking with ulem
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\color{lyxadded}{}#3}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxdeleted}[3]{{\color{lyxdeleted}\lyxsout{#3}}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxsout}[1]{\ifx\\#1\else\sout{#1}\fi}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \numberwithin{figure}{section}
    
%    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}} % #5 no date on title, if active
   \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
    \pagebreak{}
    \title{\textbf{All'inizio la democrazia era diretta}\\
    \textbf{Moritz Rittinghausen}\\
    \textbf{\Large{}e la democrazia diretta nel mondo moderno}}
    \author{\pagebreak}
    
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents{}
    
    \pagebreak{}
    
    \part*{PARTE PRIMA}
    
    \chapter{Introduzione}
    
    \section{La Germania e la democrazia: Il Vormärz più lungo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I tried to export a tex file, edit the babel clause adding [italian], [italiano] etc. and then reimport it in Lyx, nothing worked. Then, I happened to change the Lyx document settings a setting called "Language package" switching it to "Always Babel" (in my screen: "Sempre babel") and,see there, the issue resolved. As for svmono in Italian, I followed the instruction of Rich Shepard in [this](https://lyx-users.lyx.narkive.com/RYuS06UU/how-to-get-springer-class-working) page, and, see there, svmono appeared among the Lyx book classes. Needs some adaptation, but it is already a big jump forward towards humanity! The only thing that makes my sleep uneasy is that I used two out of several hundred of files contained in the Springer svmono directory. Wait and see if it breaks down.

Comment: Please, do not use the answers of your own question to make comments. If you still have not enough reputation to post comments, you can always edit your question to add relevant information to the issue. However, it is correct answer yourself , if you find the solution by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work with pdflatex in TexLive 2023 in Linux, that is what I am using, because you set the `cp1252` encoding in <kbd>Document</kbd> → <kbd>Settings...</kbd> → <kbd>Language</kbd> (or maybe LyX set this by default in your computer? Check it!). In any case, sure that you need still this encoding?

I am not a Window user but, afaik, the **`utf8`** encoding should  work well in any current OS with a modern LaTeX version:

---

[image]

---

The `uft8` is now the LaTeX default, so the fix in your code is just delete this line:

```
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
```

Unfortunately, LyX force set the encoding by default, and unfortunately again, is not `utf8` (probably `latin9`, at least in my Linux with locale set to `LANG=es_ES.UTF-8` is still that). Therefore the fix in LyX is change the encoding via menu,i.e.:
<kbd>Document</kbd> → <kbd>Settings...</kbd> → <kbd>Language</kbd> → `Encoding` dialog → Chek `Other` → Select `Unicode (utf8)`. Now the code preview pane must show the unnecessary, but not harmful:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And now it should be compiled correctly directly also in LyX. Otherwise, the problem is  your code nor LyX,  but probably the LaTeX installation (old distribution, missing packages, or so ...) or maybe the file encoding is not utf8 (warning: file encoding has nothing to do with the above LaTeX settings of `inputenc`. It is the internal file encoding. Most good plain text editors will show you that information, no matter if you are editing a .tex file or a "hello.txt" that only have "hello" inside).